# Generic SqlManager.listDatabases() not implemented

Tags: sqoop

I ran sqoop command to `list-databases` and I am getting error.

This is the sqoop command I used:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:netezza://xxxxxxxx/ --username xxxx --password xxx;
```

The error I am getting is :

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Generic SqlManager.listDatabases() not
>   implemented.

For your Information, I added Netezza jar like

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:<path to the jar>
```

Please share your knowledge on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `list-databases` syntax of sqoop works only with HSQLDB, MySQL and Oracle. Refer this [note](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_example_invocations_8) section from Sqoop User Guide.

Comment: Hi franklinsijo, Thanks for your valuable info. It helped me a lot.